# R: Parallel and data.table Error in unserialize(node$con) : error reading from connection

Tags: r, parallel-processing, data.table

**NOTE:** I fixed the issue to where my code will now run, but I have no idea why this solution worked. Any feedback is great. See edit below.

I am running into a problem with the parallel package and I think data.table. Last night, my code worked fine. However, now I am getting this error:

```
Error in unserialize(node$con) : error reading from connection.
```

As well as the same assertion failure, repeated no_core times where no_cores is the number of cores I am using in my cluster:

```
Assertion failure at kmp_runtime.cpp(6480): __kmp_thread_pool == __null.
OMP: Error #13: Assertion failure at kmp_runtime.cpp(6480).
OMP: Hint: Please submit a bug report with this message, compile and run commands used, and machine configuration info including native compiler and operating system versions. Faster response will be obtained by including all program sources.
```

Since my code worked last night, I am inclined to think some combination of packages that I had libraried allowed my code to work as I was trying to use multiple packages to do some data manipulation. But now my code no longer needs these packages, so I didn't include "library()" statements in my code.

I am using the parallel package to increase the speed at which I repeatedly call a function that simulates moments of a distribution. The function that I am calling uses data.table to estimate these moments. Below is all the code that I think is relevant and in the same order of my actual script.

```
library(data.table)
library(parallel)
Rcpp::sourceCpp('mycppcode.cpp')
nsim=100
no_cores = detectCores()-1

objective_fun = function(theta_guess, dmoments = data_moments){
  set.seed(100)
  moment.list = parLapply(cl,1:nsim,function(x) {est.moments(theta_guess)})
  moment.mat = matrix(unlist(moment.list),ncol=nsim)
  mean.moments = apply(moment.mat,1,mean)
  outval = as.numeric(t(mean.moments-dmoments)%*%(mean.moments-dmoments))
  outval
}

cl = makeCluster(no_cores,type = "FORK")
test = constrOptim(guess,objective_fun,grad=gradient_obj,
        ui=diag(11),ci=rep(0,11),method = "BFGS")
```

The est.moments function uses data.table to calculate complicated means and variances. I am only really using data.table(), setkey(), and merge().

Yes, I am making the cluster after defining the objective function. I could be doing this incorrectly as I am relatively new to the parallel package.

The only other thing worth mentioning is that I am also using Rcpp to make certain function, though the C++ code compiles and runs fine on its own.

**EDIT:** If I make a cluster at the very beginning of my code, then stop it at the end, then remake it, my code runs fine. What am I doing wrong?

```
library(data.table)
library(parallel)
Rcpp::sourceCpp('mycppcode.cpp')
nsim=100
no_cores = detectCores()-1
cl = makeCluster(no_cores,type = "FORK")

objective_fun = function(theta_guess, dmoments = data_moments){
  set.seed(100)
  moment.list = parLapply(cl,1:nsim,function(x) {est.moments(theta_guess)})
  moment.mat = matrix(unlist(moment.list),ncol=nsim)
  mean.moments = apply(moment.mat,1,mean)
  outval = as.numeric(t(mean.moments-dmoments)%*%(mean.moments-dmoments))
  outval
}

stopCluster(cl)
cl = makeCluster(no_cores,type = "FORK")
test = constrOptim(guess,objective_fun,grad=gradient_obj,
        ui=diag(11),ci=rep(0,11),method = "BFGS")
```

Note: I removed the session info because I felt it was no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Similar errors happened to me because of memory issues. It seems that your parallel computations demand much more RAM that can be supported by the system.